# Can we connect to AzureResourceGroup from Power shell running on a Local Machine instead of running it on the azure portal

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-group

Usually We run the Azure Power shell Commands on the Azure Portal. But can we run the same azure powershell commands on the local machine powershell window by any means say for suppose by connecting to Azure resource Groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install AzureRM module on the Windows machine from where you want connect to Azure.

Azure PowerShell v.5.0.1

[Install and configure Azure PowerShell - Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.0.0)

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM
```

Then use `Connect-AzureRmAccount` cmdlet to connect to Azure.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential
```

[Connect-AzureRmAccount - Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/Connect-AzureRmAccount?view=azurermps-5.7.0#examples)

Comment: Thank you @Vincent K .This article helped me but while installing powershell get module using Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force command we face an error in windows 10 os  stating the below error The module 'PackageManagement' cannot be installed or updated because the
authenticode signature of the file 'PackageManagement.cat' is not valid. So we have to run the command like Install-Module PowerShellGet -SkipPublisherCheck -Force to override this issue. Then everything went fine and then we can go ahead with creation of azure rm module.